# Consequence of $a+b=a/b+b/a$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Positive integers $a$ and $b$ are such that $a + b = \frac{a}{b} + \frac{b}{a}$. Help me to find what is the integral value of $a^2 + b^2$?

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** If $n,m$ are positive integers, then $\frac n1\ge \frac nm$, with equality exactly if $m=1$.

Thus, if either of $a$ and $b$ is *larger than* $1$, then we have $$ \frac a1+\frac b1 > \frac ab + \frac ba $$

Answer (score 1):

We first ask a somewhat different question. If $a$ and $b$ are positive integers, when is $\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{a}$ a positive integer?

Let $d$ be the greatest common divisor of $a$ and $b$, and let $a=dx$, $b=dy$. Then $\frac{x}{y}+\frac{y}{x}$ is a positive integer, and $x$ and $y$ are relatively prime. We show that $x=y=1$.

Note that $\frac{x}{y}+\frac{y}{x}=\frac{x^2+y^2}{xy}$. Suppose that one at least of $x$ and $y$, say $x$, is greater than $1$. Then some prime $p$ divides $x$, and therefore $p$ divides $xy$. But because $xy$ divides $x^2+y^2$, it follows that $p$ divides $y$, contradicting the fact that $x$ and $y$ are relatively prime.

Back to our problem! Since $\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{a}$ is an integer, we have $a=b$. But then $a+a=\frac{a}{a}+\frac{a}{a}$, and therefore $a=1$.

Answer (score 0):

***I have also tried something***

a+b=a/b+b/a solving this gives a^2+b^2-a^(2)b-b^(2)a=0

factorizing this gives (a+b)^2-ab(a+b)-2ab=0

Discriminant D=b^2-4ac imply

(ab)^2+8ab≥0

solving this gives 8≥ab observing it gives (a,b)or(b,a)=(1,1),(1,2),(2,2),(4,1),(2,3),(6,1),(1,8),(2,4)

Now only (1,1) satisfy our equation in question hence answer should be 2.